# Polish encoding - issue with split

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a file encoded in utf-8 with polish characters.
What I need to do is to play a bit with words. But when I use split(" ") list contains \xc5\x82 or \u0142

```
filename = 'patient.txt'
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
    print line.split(" ")
    print unicode(line,encoding(line),errors='ignore').split(" ")
f.close()
```

result:

```
   ﻿Pacjent lat 48 został przyjęty do Oddziału z powodu spadku tolerancji wysiłku i duszności.
['\xef\xbb\xbfPacjent', 'lat', '48', 'zosta\xc5\x82', 'przyj\xc4\x99ty', 'do', 'Oddzia\xc5\x82u', 'z', 'powodu', 'spadku', 'tolerancji', 'wysi\xc5\x82ku', 'i', 'duszno\xc5\x9bci.']
[u'Pacjent', u'lat', u'48', u'zosta\u0142', u'przyj\u0119ty', u'do', u'Oddzia\u0142u', u'z', u'powodu', u'spadku', u'tolerancji', u'wysi\u0142ku', u'i', u'duszno\u015bci.']
```

What do I need to do to have polish characters in a list? Is is possible at all?

Regards
Pawel

Comment: `ł`, in utf8: hex `C582`; in Unicode: `\u0142`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already do have Polish characters in the list. But when you print the list you only see its representation.

```
>>> print u'zosta\u0142'
został
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is actually not UTF-8 but [UTF-8-BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Use `open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-bom')`